# Как переопределить шаблон ListBoxItem при использовании привязки данных к ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Я хочу сделать список с `ItemsSource`, то есть элементы списка будут создаваться автоматически. Проблема в том, что я хочу изменить визуальную составляющую `ListBoxItem`.

Как мне указать, что нужно рендерить этот авто-ListBoxItem с определённым шаблоном?

Comment: ItemTemplate или ItemContainerStyle пробовали править?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да. Только что переопределил шаблон при помощи ItemContainerStyle. Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите ответ, ну и через ItemTemplate всё-таки проще, наверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`. Вот ссылка на пример использования [ListBox.ItemContainerStyle](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_3.php)